# Impossible to run cython module directly?

Tags: python, module, cython

I have a very basic test script for cython

test1.pyx:

```
def do_something(f):
    return f

def main():
    f = 1
    print do_something(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which I compile with:

```
cython test1.pyx
gcc -Wall -O2 -g -lm -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -Iinclude/python2.6 -o test1.so test1.c
```

And it works:

```
./bin/python -c "import test1; test1.main()"
1
```

But calling it directly as a module doesn't work:

```
./bin/python -m test1
/mypath/bin/python: No code object available for test1
```

Why does this not work? How can I get it to work to directly call a cython script?

Cython version 0.12.1

Comment: Related cython-user mailing list thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/V-i0a8r-x00/w5WFXm-asW4J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--embed` option. Here is an [**example**](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/embed)

Answer (score 3):

I put together runcython (http://github.com/Russell91/runcython) to make this easier. Using `runcython test.pyx` will build and run your cython script directly.